# how to jquery select $("#div_id").html(' php echo?

Tags: php, jquery

How to change div content by jquery with php echo content?
I have tried :

```
<script>
$("#div_id").html("
    <?php echo "asdddd"; ?>
");     
</script>
```

It show error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: have you tried it like `.html(<?php echo "asdddd"; ?>);`

Comment: yes it show undefine asdddd

Comment: or try like this : `html('<?php echo "asdddd"; ?>')` ?

Comment: the same error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: As Swati suggested, `$("#div_id").html('<?php echo "asdddd"; ?>');`  (= making sure you're wrapping double quotes with singles quotes) seems to work fine, though...

Comment: View the *rendered* html, not the source, then the issue will probably be obvious.  Can you include the **rendered** html here?

Comment: Strings delimited by single or double quotes are not allowed to contain line breaks (not without additional measures.) If your actual content that you are trying to output there is not `asdddd`, but something that might contain line breaks, try and use a template literal instead. https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-create-multi-line-string-with-template-literals-in-javascript-a3a140d0b0f6

Comment: Or apply `json_encode` on the string value, that will take care of expressing the line breaks as `\n` (or `\r\n`, depending on which kind you have there.) `json_encode` adds the double quote delimiters already, so don’t include an extra set in this case.

Comment: @CBroe is right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to try this and its working 100% .

```
<script>

$("#div_id").html('<?php echo "asdddd"; ?>');   

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

<script>
$("#div_id").html('<?php echo "asdddd"; ?>');
</script>


below is my working code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div_id"></div>

</body>

<script>
"$("#div_id").html('<?php echo "asdddd"; ?>');"    
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.